# End of statement on an ElseIf

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

End of statement expected:

ElseIf cr_titre_en IsNot Nothing And cr_titre_fr IsNot Nothing Then

```
<%
    dim cr_titre_en = contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_FR")
    dim cr_titre_fr = contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_EN")

    If cr_titre_en Is  Nothing  And cr_titre_fr Is Nothing Then
    %>
      <td>Aucun</td>
    <%

    ElseIf cr_titre_en IsNot Nothing And cr_titre_fr IsNot Nothing Then
        %>
        <td>
            FR: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_FR")%>
            EN: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_EN")%>
        </td>
        <%
    ElseIf cr_titre_en IsNot Nothing And cr_titre_fr Is Nothing Then
        %>
        <td>
             EN: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_EN")%>
        </td>
        <%
    ElseIf cr_titre_en Is Nothing And cr_titre_fr IsNot Nothing Then
        %>
        <td>
             FR: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_FR")%>
        </td>
    <%
    End If%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td>
<%
dim cr_titre_en = contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_FR")
dim cr_titre_fr = contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_EN")

If cr_titre_en Is Nothing Then
  If cr_titre_fr Is Nothing Then
    response.write "Aucun"
  else
    response.write "FR:" & cr_titre_fr  
  end if
else         
  If cr_titre_fr Is not Nothing Then response.write "FR:" & cr_titre_fr  
  response.write "EN:" & cr_titre_en
end if
%>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
    dim cr_titre_en ,cr_titre_fr
    cr_titre_en = ""
    cr_titre_fr=""


If (cr_titre_en Is Nothing)  And (cr_titre_fr Is Nothing) Then
%>
  <td>Aucun</td>
<%

ElseIf cr_titre_en Is Not Nothing And cr_titre_fr Is Not Nothing Then
    %>
    <td>
        FR: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_FR")%>
        EN: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_EN")%>
    </td>
    <%
ElseIf cr_titre_en Is Not Nothing And cr_titre_fr Is Nothing Then
    %>
    <td>
         EN: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_EN")%>
    </td>
    <%
ElseIf cr_titre_en Is Nothing And cr_titre_fr Is Not Nothing Then
    %>
    <td>
         FR: <%=contenuRow("F_CONTENU_TITRE_FR")%>
    </td>
<%
End If%>
```